# Formatting OP's code for readability without tipping them off to the problem

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Here's a situation I ran into recently, which [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-someone-elses-code) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124111/incorrect-code-edit-comment-or-provide-a-correct-answer) don't seem to cover. The OP wrote:

```
if( foo == bar )
do_stuff( fizz );
do_stuff( buzz );
```

So, formatting it for readability, the "correct" way:

```
if( foo == bar )
    do_stuff( fizz );
do_stuff( buzz );
```

However, the lack of brackets **was** part of the OP's problem. So, I did this:

```
if( foo == bar )
    do_stuff( fizz );
    do_stuff( buzz );
```

And pointed out the issue in the comments.

Does that make sense, or should I have done it the "correct" way?

Comment: Great answers--wish I could award the "answer" to all of you! I rolled back my edit and will keep this in mind going forward.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the indentation of the code is, in and of itself, a part of the problem, I wouldn't edit the indentation at all.  I don't know if I feel strongly enough to roll back an edit of someone else who changed the indentation, but I would make a point of keeping my own hands off and address the problem(s) in the answer (or comments, depending on whether or not this issue is sufficient to answer the question).

Comment: +1 for *I wouldn't edit the indentation at all*.

Answer (score 9):

Why is "tipping them off to the problem" something to avoid? Isn't that what we're here for? I would answer, assuming the lack of brackets is their problem, something like this:

---

Your problem is that you don't have brackets after your `if` statement. You seem to believe your code will behave like this:

```
if( foo == bar )
    do_stuff( fizz );
    do_stuff( buzz );
```

But since you have no brackets, it will actually behave like this:

```
if( foo == bar )
    do_stuff( fizz );
do_stuff( buzz );
```

(The compiler doesn't read indents.)

To get the behaviour you want, write the code like this:

```
if( foo == bar )
{
    do_stuff( fizz );
    do_stuff( buzz );
}
```

It's a good habit to always use the brackets to make your intensions clear, even when there is only one line to be executed when the `if` is true.

---

And I would leave the question completely unedited.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "tipping them off to the problem" is kind of the point. I wouldn't re-format either, since it's essential to understanding (a) the problem, and (b) why indentation is more important than some people seem to understand.

Comment: `"Why is "tipping them off to the problem" something to avoid? Isn't that what we're here for?"` Tipping them off to the problem by editing their question and not answering *is* a problem.  You should tip them off to the problem by answering.  I realize that's what you advocate, but I just want to emphasize that it really can be a significant problem when you answer a question through editing the answer into the question itself.

Answer (score 7):

I would not edit the code at all. Instead, I'd ask the OP to format his code first:

1. If no reply. I leave. (Which is how I usually treat uninteresting ask-and-forget questions.)
2. If he does and he notices - problem solved. Either answer in comment and/or close as too localized.
3. If he does and doesn't notice - either answer or answer in comment.

---

Alternatively, I might just a leave a single comment and leave:

> Hint: Format your code