# Adding my code to an existing answer

Tags: support

I found an answer under a question that has a code which completely doesn't work for me, but I was able to edit it on the way that it works.

However, I afraid of changing it, since I'm not sure that my code does the same as that I saw in the answer.

What to do? On demand, I may post the related answer with my code.

Comment: How different is it, and why doesn’t it work? Typo(s) = edit, minor mistake = comment, probably, mostly wrong = post your own answer. :)

Comment: Was your problem the same as the person that asked the question? If it was, I would post a new answer detailling why it didn't work and the solution you came up with.

Comment: Very closely related: [Incorrect code: edit, comment, or provide a correct answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124111)

Comment: @minitechη I meant that my compiler writes syntax error for the answered code(mistakes that appear before compiling), but I'm not sure that I'm not the only one with this problem.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt: If it’s just a missing semicolon or brace, it’s generally okay to add that as an edit.

Comment: I posted an answer; I think I was right. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not sure that the code is the same you post another answer.

For additional brownie points explain what your answer does and *why* it works. For double brownie points you also explain the differences between your answer and the other.

You never know, you may even get some reputation out of it.

If the code in the question is only incorrect because of a typo, or a really simple fix, then it's best to comment under the answer. Possibly suggest an edit if it's just a typo, as minitech suggests, as your answer would be as good as identical to the other.

Comment: Doesn't reflecting to an another answer below the question count as being "off-topic"?

Comment: No @ZoltánSchmidt, it shows awareness of the other answers and of the full details of the question; if it's close though it's best to explain the differences so others are aware of _why_ it's different. My answer is contingent on it not being a typo as per minitech's comments though.

Comment: Also, if your problem is sufficiently different from the original question, it may be worth posting a new question and checking the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" box

Comment: I don't want to take the risk with it, since I'm still learning and I don't think that I may know something that the army of programmers wouldn't know here - I may be even wrong. But of course, thanks for helping!

Comment: We all start out at the beginning @ZoltánSchmidt... there's no shame in that. You may be wrong but unless you're willing to risk it you'll never learn. It's good to be wrong occasionally because then someone can tell you why.

Comment: Curious that what you call "brownie points", I call "requirements for an upvote". :-)

Comment: Upvotes are brownie points.  Not all posts get 'em.