# Can I submit an edit only to the author of a question or answer?

Tags: feature-request

For reasons of politeness and coherence, I would usually prefer to submit my proposed edit of a question or answer only to its author. Can I do so?

### Politeness/respect

If someone has taken the trouble to compose a question or answer, they deserve the chance to review proposed changes to it. Having my edits accepted without the author's approval is literally arrogant. I don't want to do it.

Small changes can be put in comments. But extensive changes need an edit, which also gives the reviewer a delta of before/after.

### Coherence

I recently edited another's answer (I voted for it - better than mine - grrrrrrrr) to remove a vulnerability in the code. A third party with a high reputation, though no reputation at all in the programming language concerned, superimposed an edit on mine that left the code quite wrong.

- The answer's author would never have done this.
- If nobody else had seen the proposed edit, erroneous interference would be prevented.
- I am willing to accept the author's judgement.

Comment: I would leave a comment.  You can delete the comment if the author edits the post.

Comment: Nothing in the Stack Exchange universe is private. There is no private mechanism. Authors are notified of suggested edits (though others may approve/reject before the author gets around to it.) If you prefer to comment, it's a milder approach but leaves clutter (you should remove the comment when the edit has been done or the OP comments that they don't want to make that edit.)

Comment: For reference, you suggested a code edit to an answer, changing its functionality. It's generally better to leave a comment in such cases. See [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200342/234299) and [When is it appropriate to edit someone else's code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101583/234299). The high-rep user you mention simply reverted your edit to follow these guidelines.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The third party did not reverse my edit (which would have been acceptable): (s)he left enough of it to make the code fail (throwing an exception) every time. The original code worked *almost* every time. So whatever I did, the careless third party did worse. Can't I please be given the option of avoiding these futile conflicts.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg You're right. The way things are, comments are to be preferred, and I use them and delete them accordingly. But, for the reasons stated in the question, they are sometimes inadequate and often inferior to a proposed edit.

Comment: Ah, I didn't scroll over to see that they reverted one change but not the other. (Just to clarify, I'm talking about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842553/sorting-lists-inside-vectors-of-vectors/22844196#22844196).) Regardless, your suggested edit would have been better as a comment (refer to the links in my previous comment). The user who made the edit after you should have done a rollback of your edit (if anything); instead they apparently botched the code, which is just more evidence of why code edits that change functionality are discouraged.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you: agree with you almost all the way. I would change the last clause to "... which is just more evidence of why code edits that change functionality *should be addressed to the author*". Anyway, I see that the example's been mended :). I can take off the Mr Angry mask for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for such a feature. An author will get a notification when one of his posts got edited or an edit was suggested.

If the author does not like the edit, he can roll it back.

Comment: OP = Original Poster = author.

Comment: @Thumbnail see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms OP stands for Original Poster