# Should I make SSCCE out of OP's code and where is the optimal borderline?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

Like many people here, I do hate code dumps and often the question is really about an error in one line in a couple of hundred lines and likely to be reproduced with a short code block. Should I edit such questions removing irrelevant code or leave them alone?

Inspired by this question: [Can't convert int object to str implicitly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032377/cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly-error)

Here an editor removed all the code leaving one line, which makes question lacking sufficient information, that is the types of variables. After a short edit war, I decided to edit it into a reproducible example which still keeps the structure of OP's code, but reproduces the error. After doing it I started to doubt if this is the right course of action, because the code is now very different from the original and while OP should've done it him/her-self, it is apparently [not encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question) to do it ourselves instead.

On one hand, keeping a huge amount of irrelevant code in question is useless and pollutes SO. On the other hand, if I commit to editing it to SSCCE, I will not only risk obscuring the original question, I will become a source of producing a multitude of exact duplicate questions.

What is the right course of action in such situations?

Comment: Watching that "edit war" go down, I definitely thought a single line was woefully inadequate. Your current edit seems the ideal to me.

Comment: That said, pointing OP to (and closing as dupe of) a relevant question is ideal. You did that too.

Comment: @mhlester Yep, I thought that there must be a dupe for this one and certainly there was. It is not always the case however...

Comment: Do you know the actual answer? Typically in similar situations when I do, I create an *answer* that first says, "Let's reduce this to a minimal example which demonstrates the problem... [problem] Now, it's happening because of [X], and it can be fixed by doing [Y]." If you *don't* know the answer, it's tougher - but I would encourage the OP to edit instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that's a good point. A *major* part of the solution is in learning how to boil down the actual problem (it wasn't in this case, but often is)